# Why do people think Tupac Shakur is still alive?

Tags: rap

On September 7, 1996, Tupac Shakur died in a drive-by shooting in Las Vegas. However, many conspiracy theorists don’t believe that Shakur is dead, and many believe he faked his death after he was hospitalized.

Why would Tupac Shakur fake his death and why do people think Tupac Shakur is still alive?

Comment: There are always conspiracy theorists for all sorts of things. There is still the conspiracy that Elvis isn't dead, and he just wanted out of the constant playing, acting, and touring. There are those who think singers fake death to raise popularity of their songs (nostalgia etc.). You can speculate all you like. There will also be other ideas and "reasons" for conspiracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One contributing factor was the sheer volume of material that's been released following his death (seven albums and many singles), leading people to believe he continued his career in secret and benefitting from the increase in interest and sales that so many artists of all varieties sometime receive following their deaths.